# How to store values from a list into an array of objects in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have a state that is similar to this

```
this.state = {
      var: "",
      arr1: [{
        pName: "",
        priority: ""
      }],
      other: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    }
```

in my render() I list out the contents of the "other" array, and next to it, a user can put any number, which would be their ranking (doesn't matter if repeated) of the items in the "other array as shown below

```
  <Row className="App">
    <ul>
      {this.state.other.map((item, index) =>
        <li key={index}>{item}<Input className="rankCols" type="number" id="ranking" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /></li>
        )}
    </ul>
  </Row>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to store the "item" from the list and the matching "ranking" into the "arr1" so that if a user ranks item1 as "3", item2 as "1" and item3 as "2", the arr1 would be updated to be

```
arr1: [{
  pName: "item1",
  priority: "3"
  },
  {
  pName: "item2",
  priority: "1"
  },
  {
  pName: "item3",
  priority: "2"
  }]
```

The handleChange() works updating the value that the user inputs

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

I'm not sure if it can be done this way or if I'd have to use some type of loop in order to store each item along with its priority.

Comment: Is the contents of `other` array fixed? Also please provide the implementation of `handleChange`.

Comment: @Nuhman yes, the "other" array was pulled from a json object and stored into it.

Comment: @MarianaGomez-Kusnecov You can mark and accept the answer if its works fine, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to find if the items priority already exists in your array and update it if present or else add it in the array. Also you would need to provide which item you are updating to handleChange

```
   this.state = {
      var: "",
      arr1: [],
      other: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    }
```

---

```
  <Row className="App">
    <ul>
      {this.state.other.map((item, index) =>
        <li key={index}>{item}<Input className="rankCols" type="number" id="ranking" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item)} /></li>
        )}
    </ul>
  </Row>
```

---

```
handleChange = (item,event) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    this.setState(prev => {
      const idx = prev.arr1.findIndex(obj => obj.pName === item)
      if(idx > -1) {
           return {
              arr1: [...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx), {pName: item, priority: value}, ...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx + 1)]
           }
      } else {
          return {
              arr1: prev.arr1.concat([{pName: item, priority: value}])
           }
      }

    }));
  }
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Line 88:  'arr1' is not defined  no-undef" even though my state looks the same. line 88 is "arr1: arr1.concat([{pName: item, priority: value}])"

Comment: Updated my answer, change `arr1: arr1.concat([{pName: item, priority: value}])` to `arr1: prev.arr1.concat([{pName: item, priority: value}])`